# Does not storing passwords in browser really matter given cookie hijacking exists?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, cookies

I see lots of articles suggesting not storing passwords in the browser, and it made perfect sense to me, if I can access this data easily, an attacker probably can too.

But then I found out about cookie hijacking, and it seems to me that if your browser is compromised you are already susceptible to this attack that seems much worse (because it can even bypass MFA, since the user is already authenticated).

Stealing passwords stored in the browser would still be dangerous because an attacker could try these passwords in other services, but if I'm already using different passwords for each service, and MFA whenever possible, is the extra security from not storing passwords in browser really worth the convenience loss?

Comment: I think your question really is, "how much of a threat is cookie hijacking?"

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178663/why-isnt-stealing-cookies-enough-to-authenticate and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151630/cookie-hijacking-bypassing-authentication

Comment: I assumed cookie hijacking was "easy" and dangerous, given the wave of channels being hijacked in youtube(like linus tech tips some time ago). It seems plausible that if the browser is compromised, anything you can do without authentication can be exploited, so if I already have an open session(and many websites leave sessions opened forever), an atacker can use that session

Comment: This is what's actually happening with the Youtube hacks: https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/youtubers-takeovers/48375/

Comment: As you can see from the other links, there is usually more going on to protect a session. So, 1. it's not a universal problem, and 2. you can't compare the threats and risks between the *potential* for cookie passing on a vulnerable site and storing all passwords in the browser's local storage.

Comment: @schroeder, the Local Storage is not where the passwords are stored.. there typically stored in a Software Security enclave. the Local storage is a specific type of storage available through the Javascript engine. (as to not confuse others, better not use local storage)

Comment: @LvB I wasn't meaning "Local Storage" <sup>TM</sup> but "stored locally"

Comment: I know... but I also take it you get my response... form a security perspective I get your use... but I have talked to too many Javascript dev's to not point out this common pitfall..

(maybe I should have worded my comment a tad differently I was being a little lazy and copy pasted a reply i end not 30 minutes before and tweaked it for you...)

Comment: @LvB yep, just hoping there wasn't a language snafu

Comment: If someone steals your cookies, it does not necessarily mean they have your passwords.  Most (if not all) sites would tokenize and/or hash a "remember me" type cookie (non-reversible) and you can't get the actual login password from that.   (secure sites would require you to enter the password when changing account info or doing other sensitive actions)  If they are able to steal the cookieDB, they can also steal the stored passwordsDB.  That includes reversible values.  (They can get the actual passwords from that...)

Comment: having said that the encrypted DBs on Windows in Chrome, for instance, are much more secure (DPAPI for encryption) than on Linux (key is "peanuts" last I checked).   Stealing the file would not be enough if DPAPI encryption is used, they'd probably need to be able to execute code on that machine to decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, lets see. is having a token that is only valid for 'x' time as much of a threat as having the keys to make new tokens....

aside from the answer [178663... why stealing cookie isn't enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178663/why-isnt-stealing-cookies-enough-to-authenticate)
lets look into what exactly is the difference between these 2 type of tokens.

- Session token:

  - has limited lifetime
  - can be locked to a connection / IP / Device.
  - is given after  authentication & authorization.
- User name & Password (called: Credentials)

  - is valid until changed at the source of truth.
  - can not be (easily) locked to connection /IP /Device.
  - can be used to get (new) Session tokens
  - Can typically be used in parallel with the original owner without notice.
  - is often shared on multiple places. (password sharing problem...)

in conclusion, while both a token and a credential can be used to do requests in the users name. only 1 has real `re-use` capability.
There are also a myriad of methods to enhance the security of session tokens and limit there abusive use (something Google still hasn't perfected for there high value targets like Youtubers).

another thing is that you can lock sessions to devices and connections... and even make them have short lifetime. which would make the window of effective use small.

in short, storing passwords in your browser is better than nothing, but still a bad idea.. the session tokens stored in browsers are much less an issue, if security measures are properly employed by the application builder.